# Python write 2 lists and Pandas DataFrames to csv/excel sequentially

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have these Python lists and Pandas Dataframes:

```
list_1 = ['Intro line here - record of method function:']
list_2 = ['Record of local minimum follows:']

print df_1
   Col_A    Col_B
  3.4443    1.443
 10.8876    11.99

print df2
Trial_1  Trial_2  Trial_3
    1.1     1.49    775.9
   11.5     9.57     87.3
 384.61   77.964     63.7
  12.49    0.156      1.9
 112.11   11.847    178.3
```

Here is what I want in the output csv or excel file - either csv or excel would work for me:

```
Intro line here - record of method function:
   Col_A    Col_B
  3.4443    1.443
 10.8876    11.99
Record of local minimum follows:
Trial_1  Trial_2  Trial_3
    1.1     1.49    775.9
   11.5     9.57     87.3
 384.61   77.964     63.7
  12.49    0.156      1.9
 112.11   11.847    178.3
```

Is there a way to write the list, Pandas, list, Pandas in this order to the csv or excel file?

Comment: Why are you putting the string 'Intro line here - record of method function:' and 'Record of local minimum follows:' into lists.  Why not just `string_1='Intro line here - record of method function:'`?

Comment: It is just the way I created those 2 strings - I assigned them to separate lists. I could have also used `list = ['Intro line here - record of method function:', 'list_2 = ['Record of local minimum follows:']`. Your approach is also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.to_csv()` accepts a file handle as input, not just a file name. So you can open a file handle and write multiple files into it. Here's an example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open('output.csv', 'w') as handle:
    for line in list_1:
        print(line, handle)
    df1.to_csv(handle, index=False)
    for line in list_2:
        print(line, handle)
    df2.to_csv(handle, index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#) provides your desired functionality:

```
import csv
with open('SO Example.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(list_1)
    writer.writerow(df1.columns)
    writer.writerows(df1.values)
    writer.writerow(list_2)
    writer.writerow(df2.columns)
    writer.writerows(df2.values)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution - it worked. I ended up using a mixture of solutions. For writing the lists to the csv file, I used your approach. For writing the Pandas DataFrames, I used the approach in the above reply (S Anand) - I found that approach slighly more convenient to write the dataframe since I did not need to specify columns and values separately.